# UILabel Text with Multiple Font Colors

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, textcolor

Is there a way to have the `textColor` property of a `UILabel` be two different `UIColors`? Basically I'm trying to make the first character in the `UILabel` `text property` to be `greenColor` and the rest be `blackColor`. I would like to avoid using two different `UILabels` because I may want to change the position in the text of the green character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UILabel doesnot supprt this property...

Use should use NSAttributedString... and use controllers for drawing NSAttributesString...

[Controller for NSAttributedString](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Ali-Cocoa-Classes)

**UPDATE:**

From iOS 6 you can do the following :

```
label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Refer to this ques i have acieved what u want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208282/advance-search-implementation-in-iphone/4208329#4208329

Comment: Downvoted for pointing us to a big repository of your code instead of answering directly.

Comment: @mehulpatel UILabel now supports NSAttributedString

Answer (score 7):

Starting from ios 6 you can do the following :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:string];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,3)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(4,9)];
cell.label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
        func setColorForText(textToFind: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
         let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
          if range != nil {
            self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
          }
        }

}


func setColoredLabel() {
        var string: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "My label with red blue and green colored text")
        string.setColorForText(textToFind: "red", withColor: UIColor.red)
        string.setColorForText(textToFind: "blue", withColor: UIColor.blue)
        string.setColorForText(textToFind: "green", withColor: UIColor.green)
        mylabel.attributedText = string
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but change NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor with NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Answer (score 2):

NSAttributedStrings support mixed fonts, styles, and colors in the same string, but aren't currently supported by any standard UIKit controls. That said, you should check out [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/). It's a simple, performant replacement for UILabel that will allow you to display rich text really easily.

Answer (score 1):

No - Apple say you should use HTML in a `UIWebView` if you need formatted text. (See the note in the overview section of the [UITextView API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html).)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative way is to create multiple labels with difference color and layout them next to each other. Try to make the label's background color transparent. It may be tedious but should work.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible - you need to draw on your own or compose using several labels.

If you can accept 3.2 compatibility, you might have a look at `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

not currently possible, usually you would use an NSAttributedString, but to use this on iOS you would need to roll your own label. you may be able to work round this using a UIWebView, but I don't like to do that, it seems heavy handed.