# How to make particular word colored : coming from localized string file of iOS

Tags: ios, colors, localization

I would like to make particular word colored like this  :

Text in English :-

[image: English]

Same place text in French :-

[image: French]

These text are came from localized string file. And I found solution with the string range property `NSMakeRange(0,3)` for attributed text [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306190/uilabel-text-with-multiple-font-colors). This I don't want since text will differ for Localized language string. FYI, I placed text in UITextView.
So how can I achieve this by simple way? Is there any solution that can fix problem in *Localized string file* itself.

Comment: You would have to have sentence and words (you want to color) localized separately so that you can find your words after localization. This is not iOS problem, it is logical issue.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is a few years late, but I solved the problem by allowing HTML in my localizable strings.  For example:

```
"emergency" = "This is a test of the <span style=\"color:red\">emergency</span> broadcast system.";
```

Of course, this alone won't solve the problem, because the localizable string files in IOS don't natively support any sort of HTML/XML annotation.  So, you need to process the HTML yourself when you extract the string in your swift code.  Here is how I did it:

```
        // Get the localized string
        let localized = NSLocalizedString("emergency", comment: "")
        
        // Prepend an html header to the string select the primary font and color.
        // The settings on the UITextView or UILabel will be ignored, so you need to do this
        let htmlString = "<span style=\"color:yellow;font-size:24px;font-family:-apple-system\">" + localized
        
        // perform the magic to turn the html string into an NSAttributedString
        let data = NSString(string: htmlString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data!,
                                          options: [
                                            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)

            // Show the NSAttributedString in your help UITextView (or anywhere else)
            help.attributedText = attributedString
        } catch {
            print("There was a problem")
        }
```

This example gives you yellow, 24-point, apple system font text.  The localizable string marked the word "emergency" as red, and it will be displayed in red in the final display.

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet might be used for achieving yourrequirement

```
  UITextView *textView = //YourTextView

 NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: textView.attributedText];
        [attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                               value:[UIColor redColor]
                               range:[textView.text rangeOfString:blueString]];

        [attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                               value:[UIColor blueColor]
                               range:[textView.text rangeOfString:redString]];
        [textView setAttributedText: attributedText];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but as I mentioned in the question I can't use NSMakeRange() since text will differ for language settings!. I hope you got it.

Comment: Sorry it was a copy paste error. See my edit Where redString is your string parameter

Comment: I think the key to this solution is that the variables redString and blueString would represent the localized languange string.  So iDev's code will seek "red" and "blue" in English, but will find and color "rouge" and "bleu" in French.  Since he is calling `rangeOfString:` it will find those strings wherever they are in the localized text.

Comment: redColor is not the exact string it is a variable that has a string that need to be in red color

Comment: Thanks for reply, @iDEV: How can I recognize the text "red" in English and "rouge" in French to be applied with color from the whole string? . Is there any solution that can fix problem in Localized string file itself??

Comment: you should know which part of string you are going to show in different color