# Integrating HTML tags with text

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to directly use HTML tags in iPhone SDK? I was wondering how could I display the following text using HTML in a UILabel :

> My *name* is **Nitish** and I am **24** years *old*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be allowed. Look at following post as well:

- [iPhone - UILabel containing text with multiple fonts at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time/1417365#1417365)

Look at this alternative as well:

- [iPhone - UILabel containing text with multiple fonts at the same time (another asnwer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417346/iphone-uilabel-containing-text-with-multiple-fonts-at-the-same-time/1532634#1532634)

Comment: My text is bold and italic at different positions. There it is suggested to take two UILabels. This means more rich is the text, more UILabels I have to take. Right?

Comment: What other options do I have?

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208282/advance-search-implementation-in-iphone/4208329#4208329.. May this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use UILabel to display richtext, you will have to move to CoreText.
https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML will allow you to create NASttributeString from HTML source.

Comment: Read the source and documentation on the Apple developer website. There is an example app in the download.

Answer (score 0):

This library might help.

https://github.com/elijahdou/RTLabel

Simple rich text display for iOS using html-like markups